# Argument of type 'string | JwtPayload' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, jwt

I am using Typescript with Express and using JWT for Bearer Authorization. Now the case is, I am writing the authorize middleware with JWT as mentioned and am trying to extract current user from the JWT token.

Code here:

```
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import {NextFunction, Response, Request} from "express";
import {
    VerifyOptions,
    Algorithm,
    JsonWebTokenError,
    TokenExpiredError,
    NotBeforeError,
    Secret,
    JwtPayload
} from "jsonwebtoken";


 ....       

try {
            

    // Verify the token
    let result = jwt.verify(authToken, accessTokenSecret, accessTokenOptions)

    console.log("Type of: String"+(result instanceof String) )

    console.log("Type of: JwtPayload " + (result instanceof JwtPayload) ); // Error



    next();
} catch (error){
   ...
}

}
```

I am trying to check if result is instance of JwtPayload. However, JwtPayload is an interface. So, I keep getting this error that **Argument of type 'string | JwtPayload' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.**

Assume that the token is verified all the time.

Result has following data!

```
{
    user: {id: 1, username: 'ariel'},
    iat: 1234,
    exp: 1278
}
```

I am just trying to parse the user from the result. However, I keep getting the error mentioned in the header.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have installed @types/jsonwebtoken

Then you can do:

```
import * as jwt from "jsonwebtoken"
import type { JwtPayload } from "jsonwebtoken"

...

let result = jwt.verify(authToken, accessTokenSecret, accessTokenOptions) as JwtPayload
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where exactly your problem is (can't see it in the snippet), but try to use type predicates.
i.e.

```
function isJWTPayload(value: JWTPayload | String): value is JWTPayload {
  return (value as isJWTPayload).id !== undefined;
}
```

See here for more
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-type-predicates

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but for anyone else,

```
const result: string | JwtPayload = jwt.verify(authToken, accessTokenSecret, accessTokenOptions)
if (result === 'undefined' || typeof result === 'string') {
next(new UnAuthenticatedError('invalid token'))
return
}
console.log(result)
```

This checks if the value of result is string or undefined, throws an error but if its the standard jwtpayload it goes through,